# Creating vector space

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I've got a question:
I have a lot of documents and each line built by some pattern.
Of course, I have this array of patterns.

I want to create some vector space, then to vector this patterns by some rule (I have no ideas about what is this rule yet..) - i.e. to make this patterns like "centroids" of my vector space.
Then to vector each line of the current document (again by this rule) and to count the closet centroid to this line (i.e. minimum of the distance between two vectors).

I don't know how can I do this? 
I know about sklearn libraries and CountVectorizer/TfidfVectorizer/HashingVectorizer - but this depends on the vocabulary size. But, again, I have a lot of documents, that's why it'll be too much words in vocabulary (if do this way, but in next new document it can be new word which this vocabulary wouldn't have. That's way this is wrong way to solve my problem)
Also Keras library with it's Text Preprocessing won't solve my problem two. E.x. "one hot" encodes a text into a list of word indexes of size . But each document may have different size and of course the order. That's way comparing two vectors may give big distance, but in fact this vectors (words, that encoded by this vectors) are very similar.

Comment: If I have understood correctly what you want that each sentence of these documents to be represented as a point in a vectorial space and to be able to find the closest one (here is not clear if the closest sentence in the given document or among all the other document). 1) you could build a word2vec dictionary using all the text corpora (all your documents, so that you have all the possible words in your dictionary) 2) encode the sentence with doc2vec (In your case a sentence is a paragraph). Gensim library is a good implementation for this kind of analysis

Comment: @Roberto thank you for the answer! But I think, that it's not a good way to solve my problem too. I can train by word2vec (or doc2vec) model my documents. But in future I can receive a new one, which contains absolutely new line with information. And, as you know, I can't re-train my word2vec/doc2vec model to this news

Comment: I'm not sure that I have understood your question then. Probably if you try to edit it giving a bit more of context you can find better answer. Just keep in mind that you can use dictionary from google that are quite comprehensive and that you can infer the doc2vec for a new document with "infer_vector".

Comment: @Roberto Yes, I know about this (w2v/d2v), but unfortunately I have a lot of technical specific terms (my task is not about artistic text or smth else. Terms automatically generated by system). And I'm sure that they (terms) won't be in Google dictionary. That's why I will have again a lot of new "unknown" for dictionary words..

Comment: This is very abstract without a better idea of what the ;'lines' are, and what the real final goal is. (*Why* do you want to model the lines this way, and then compare them this way? What's the ultimate end purpose?)

Comment: @gojomo each document has lots of lines. Line is a typical sentence generated the system. Lines splits by '\n' between themselves. 
Centroid is some pattern (some sentence). Word2Vec creates vector for each word. So, if use w2v I don't know what it will be coordinates of Centroid (group of words). Maybe it will be optimize to use d2v and assign vector to each sentence? But I don't know, how to do it yet..

Comment: From your description, I still have no idea what your 'words' are and why you want to do any of this. What's the benefit to your end-users? Search retrieval? Content recommendation? Classification?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/k-means-clustering-example-word2vec/ except with sentences as basis for vectors instead of words?

Comment: It's not so good idea because I need to update my vocabulary of words. As I know there isn't any model that can update it's own vocabulary
@gojomo Is it true that w2v in gensim can update vocabulary now? It's a new thing.